# PAM EXAM configuration dependency demanding older JAR when newer is available

Tags: configuration, dependencies, osgi, pax-exam

I'm struggling with a PAX EXAM configuration for integration tests of a project I've started working some weeks ago.

The major problem are regarding the dependencies of the bundles I'm intending to test, but I was always able to evolve for each problem, but now I'm really stuck.

Below I'm listing the current version of my @Configuration method:

```
@Configuration
public Option[] configure() {

// Runs outside the OSGi framework
return options(
    junitBundles(),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "antlr", "antlr" ).version( "2.7.7" ) ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "com.fasterxml", "classmate" ).version( "1.3.0" ) ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.javassist", "javassist" ).version( "3.18.1-GA" ) ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.jboss.logging", "jboss-logging" ).version( "3.1.0.GA" ) ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "dom4j", "dom4j" ).version( "1.6.1" ) ),
    //wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api" ).version( "1.0.1.Final" ) ),
    mavenBundle( "javax.persistence", "com.springsource.javax.persistence" ).version( "2.0.0" ),

    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction", "jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec" ).version( "1.0.1.Final" ) ),
    //wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "javax.transaction", "javax.transaction-api" ).version( "1.2" ) ),
    //wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "javax.enterprise", "cdi-api" ).version( "1.0-SP4" ) ),
    //wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor", "jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec" ).version( "1.0.0.Beta1" ) ),

    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.jboss", "jandex" ).version( "1.0.3.Final" ) ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.hibernate", "hibernate-core" ).version( "4.2.21.Final" ) ),

    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-beans" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.beans" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-context" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.context" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-core" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.core" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-aop" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.aop" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-jdbc" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.jdbc" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-tx" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.tx" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "aopalliance", "aopalliance" ).version( "1.0" ) ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework.osgi", "spring-osgi-core" ).version( "1.2.1" ) ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework.osgi", "spring-osgi-annotation" ).version( "1.2.1" ) ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework.osgi", "spring-osgi-extender" ).version( "1.2.1" ) ),

    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "commons-lang", "commons-lang" ).version( "2.6" ) ),
    wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.hibernate.common", "hibernate-commons-annotations" ).version( "4.0.2.Final" ) );
}
```

I removed our business dependencies because they are not necessary for the explanation.

Spring OSGI dependencies ("spring-osgi-core", "spring-osgi-annotation", etc) are dependent of version "2.5.6" of Spring Framework, which I'm already fulfilling with versions "3.2.5.RELEASE" of those libs, but for some reason the old versions are still getting enforced as could be seen by erros below:

```
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve br.com.mycompany.myapplication.osgi.entity.interceptor.entity-interceptor [39](R 39.0): missing requirement [br.com.mycompany.myapplication.osgi.entity.interceptor.entity-interceptor [39](R 39.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotation)(version>=1.2.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotations [33](R 33.0): missing requirement [org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotations [33](R 33.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.beans)(version>=2.5.6)(!(version>=4.0.0)))] Unresolved requirements: [[br.com.mycompany.myapplication.osgi.entity.interceptor.entity-interceptor [39](R 39.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotation)(version>=1.2.0))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve br.com.mycompany.myapplication.api.log.application-log-service [40](R 40.0): missing requirement [br.com.mycompany.myapplication.api.log.application-log-service [40](R 40.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=br.com.mycompany.myapplication.osgi.entity.interceptor.repository) [caused by: Unable to resolve br.com.mycompany.myapplication.osgi.entity.interceptor.entity-interceptor [39](R 39.0): missing requirement [br.com.mycompany.myapplication.osgi.entity.interceptor.entity-interceptor [39](R 39.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotation)(version>=1.2.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotations [33](R 33.0): missing requirement [org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotations [33](R 33.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.beans)(version>=2.5.6)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[br.com.mycompany.myapplication.api.log.application-log-service [40](R 40.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=br.com.mycompany.myapplication.osgi.entity.interceptor.repository)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR: Bundle br.com.mycompany.myapplication.api.log.application-log-service [40] Error starting file:/tmp/1533155354575-0/pax-exam-downloads/br.com.mycompany.myapplication.api.log.application-log-service_1.46.0.SNAPSHOT.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve br.com.mycompany.myapplication.api.log.application-log-service [40](R 40.0): missing requirement [br.com.mycompany.myapplication.api.log.application-log-service [40](R 40.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=br.com.mycompany.myapplication.osgi.entity.interceptor.repository) [caused by: Unable to resolve br.com.mycompany.myapplication.osgi.entity.interceptor.entity-interceptor [39](R 39.0): missing requirement [br.com.mycompany.myapplication.osgi.entity.interceptor.entity-interceptor [39](R 39.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotation)(version>=1.2.0)) [caused by: Unable to resolve org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotations [33](R 33.0): missing requirement [org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotations [33](R 33.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.beans)(version>=2.5.6)(!(version>=4.0.0)))]] Unresolved requirements: [[br.com.mycompany.myapplication.api.log.application-log-service [40](R 40.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=br.com.mycompany.myapplication.osgi.entity.interceptor.repository)])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve br.com.mycompany.myapplication.api.log.listener.application-log-listener [41](R 41.0): missing requirement [br.com.mycompany.myapplication.api.log.listener.application-log-listener [41](R 41.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=br.com.mycompany.idpclient.model) Unresolved requirements: [[br.com.mycompany.myapplication.api.log.listener.application-log-listener [41](R 41.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=br.com.mycompany.idpclient.model)]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Does anyone have any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks a lot and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You should not wrap all the bundles on your own. Sometimes making an OSGi bundle requires more than the auto wrapping can provide. A good approach is to check what Apache Karaf uses.

Spring and many other libs you need are provided by service mix bundles.

Try this:

```
Download and start Apache Karaf 4.1.5
feature:install spring hibernate transaction
la -s
```

So you see what bundles karaf installs for spring. These should work better for your case.

Apart from that I would really try to get away from spring if you want to use OSGi. Spring was known to cause lots of issues in OSGi and the newer versions are even less compatible.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian for you quick reply. I'm not used with OSGI and some other technologies used on this project. For instance, they use here is Apache Felix and not Karaf, so I don't know if your suggestion is applicable in such case. My methodology to get the list of bundles I have untill now was to add one by one as missed dependency errors where shown. And, to choose the specific maven dependency/bundle version, I looked at dependency tree of the bundle I want to test and in the Felix Web Console. Those spring with this specific version are being used all over application. Any thoughts?

Comment: If those bundles are used in production then it makes sense to also use them in your test. Keep in mind though that wrap not always produces correct bundles.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround the problem by wrapping the "org.springframework" dependencies in order to change their manifest, like below:

```
wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-beans" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.beans" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" )
    .exports( "*;version=3.2.5.RELEASE" ).overwriteManifest( WrappedUrlProvisionOption.OverwriteMode.MERGE ),
wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-core" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.core" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" )
    .exports( "*;version=3.2.5.RELEASE" ).overwriteManifest( WrappedUrlProvisionOption.OverwriteMode.MERGE ),
wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-context" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.context" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" )
    .exports( "*;version=3.2.5.RELEASE" ).overwriteManifest( WrappedUrlProvisionOption.OverwriteMode.MERGE ),
wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-jdbc" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.jdbc" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" )
    .exports( "*;version=3.2.5.RELEASE" ).overwriteManifest( WrappedUrlProvisionOption.OverwriteMode.MERGE ),
wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-aop" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.aop" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" )
    .exports( "*;version=3.2.5.RELEASE" ).overwriteManifest( WrappedUrlProvisionOption.OverwriteMode.MERGE ),
wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-orm" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.orm" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" )
    .exports( "*;version=3.2.5.RELEASE" ).overwriteManifest( WrappedUrlProvisionOption.OverwriteMode.MERGE ),
wrappedBundle( mavenBundle( "org.springframework", "spring-tx" ).version( "3.2.5.RELEASE" ) ).bundleSymbolicName( "org.springframework.transaction" ).bundleVersion( "3.2.5.RELEASE" )
    .exports( "*;version=3.2.5.RELEASE" ).overwriteManifest( WrappedUrlProvisionOption.OverwriteMode.MERGE ),
```

With this change, the "org.springframework.osgi" dependencies stop asking for the older "2.5.6" version of "org.springframework" libs.

Now I'm facing a different problem to get everyghing running as exposed on another question: [PAX EXAM Rest Endpoint not available for felix integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877737/pax-exam-rest-endpoint-not-available-for-felix-integration-test).